# Android application establishing connections to a server?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql-server

I've recently began working on an android application which will need access to a server. So I was told that a VPS was my best bet, so I went and purchased a VPS. I've set up the VPS, so now it has a db on there (MySQL).

Now the problem is, I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. I've done some research now for a while but haven't been able to find anything. Directly in the android app I've been trying to do some jdbc stuff or some jsch, but I've read somewhere (I think a comment on here) that android doesn't support jdbc? So what are some common architectures or ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To establish a connection to server, you need to have a script at the server end to receive and perform some action on input connection. So first step would be to write a simple script (I would suggest PHP).

Now, you must create a connection from android to the said server. You can use AsyncTask or spawn a new thread to perform any network related operations, because no network operation can run on UI thread. Sample code:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  //perform network operation and return response
  URL url = new URL("link.to.your.VPS.script");
  //now make a connection
  HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
  //get response code
  conn.getResponseCode();

  return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v){

}
}
```

You can run this code from your activity by

```
new BackgroundTask().execute();
```

This is just a starter. You can improve on this by posting parameters to your PHP code and connect PHP code to MySql DB

**P.S.**
I was in your place a year ago and hence I am more than happy to help. But the next time you post on StackOverfllow, make sure your question is specific.

Comment: I wasn't aware this question was still open. This was posted nearly 4 years ago and has long been solved. Thank you for your response though. Also, I have since posted questions with much more detail. But thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to access data is to access it as a REST service. Android has good support for fetching and parsing JSON. You have to expose the data that you want on the Android application as a REST service and use Androids `HttpClient` library to access it